# No automatic line-break in textarea in Joomla Backend

Tags: joomla, textarea, joomla2.5, line-breaks, joomla-module

I'm writing a Module for Joomla! 2.5. In my Backend I've got a textarea, in which values should be written line by line. If the value is to big the line breaks and it looks really confusing and chaotic.

In normal html I would add a `wrap="off"` to the textarea-tag (I know it's not conform html, but it works), but the textarea is defined in the module's xml-file:

```
<field name="content" type="textarea" label="LWTAGCLOUD_CONTENT_LABEL" description="LWTAGCLOUD_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION" rows="20" cols="60" class="lw_tagcloud_textarea" default="VALUE; LINK"></field>
```

Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot solve the problem using css only, and since you cannot add `wrap="off"` to the textarea type in Joomla, what you could do is to create a custom parameter type, the same like textarea, just with `wrap=off` already defined.

Comment: sorry for the late answer, but i have a look on it

Answer (score 0):

just use `&#13;&#10;` for line break !
hope this help for anyone who ask